# Use awk to print $0 using the same format for all columns

Tags: linux, string, bash, text, awk

Taking an example, I have a file with one line

```
0.1 35 23.0e3 4.0D+03
```

and I'd like to convert it to a nicely formatted file like

```
1.00e-01 3.50e+01 2.30e+04 4.00e+03
```

I know we can do this in `awk` using the `printf` statement, but that would be tedious if the number of columns is big. I was wondering if there is a way to set the format for all columns, and just use `print $0`?

Comment: Why not just loop until `NF`?

Comment: Is the fourth column value really valid? `4.0D+03`? which notation is that?

Comment: Show us your code that sets the format for each field individually and we can help you automate using that form for all fields in a loop.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering this input:

```
$ a=$'0.1 35 23e3\n0.2 36 24e3';echo "$a"
0.1 35 23e3
0.2 36 24e3
```

This gnu awk will achieve what you expect without looping over the fields:

```
$ echo "$a" |awk '{printf "%.2e%s",$0,RT}' RS="[ ]|\n"
1.00e-01 3.50e+01 2.30e+04
2.00e-01 3.60e+01 2.40e+04
```

I have intentionally exclude `4.0D+03` since does not seem valid.